# JQuery .each() "this" keyword vs JS Class "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, object

I am trying to add an .each() method to a JS class declaration. However, I think the two `this` keywords are conflicting. Attempts to return the class variable using `this` returns `undefined`.

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(parameterA, parameterB){
    this.parameterA = parameterA;
    this.myClassMethod = this.myClassMethod.bind(this);
  }

  myClassMethod(){
    $('.class').each(function(){
      console.log(this.parameterA); //Returns undefined
    }
  }

}

var test = MyClass(parameterA, parameterB);
```

Comment: It logs undefined because the anonymous each function is not bound to the class context.

Comment: Well, `this` in the `each()` refers to the current item in the each loop, not the class `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the `each` function to the class context.

```js
class MyClass{
  constructor(parameterA, parameterB){
    this.parameterA = parameterA;
  }

  myClassMethod(){
    $('.class').each(function(){
      console.log(this.parameterA); // Should log 'a'
    }.bind(this));
  }

}

$(function() {
  const test = new MyClass('a', 'b');
  
  test.myClassMethod();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
</div>
<div class="class">
</div>
<div class="class">
</div>
<div class="class">
</div>
<div class="class">
</div>
```